# How can I remove a vertical guide in Xcode in Interface Builder?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I added a vertical guide in my nib file by using "Editor->Add Vertical Guide".  However, now I want to get rid of it and I don't see any option to do that?  I have the same problem with Horizontal guides.  Help!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

To remove the horizontal or vertical guides, simply select the guide with your mouse and drag it off the nib view in Interface Builder, then it will show a "poof" cloud and then it is deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Remember to drag **vertical guides horizontally** and **horizontal guides vertically** out of the window's bounds Then you should see the "Poof"!

Also, I had to add an additional guide to my view in order to make the ones that were previously added visible.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me also, but had to restart Xcode. Without restart "move" cursor didn't appear for some reason.

Comment: Not necessarily to reopen Xcode, you may just open other file (source, image, other xib) and go back to your xib.